# Как реализовать: лежит ли объект в Map?

Tags: java

В работе необходима вот такой объект:

```
Map<RealProfile, ArrayList<ModelledProfile>> example = new HashMap<RealProfile, ArrayList<ModelledProfile>>();
```

Дальше потребуется определять **лежит ли объект класса RealProfile в этой мапе или нет**, но сравниваться должны не все поля.

Как это реализовать?

Вот сам класс RealProfile

```
public class RealProfile {

private String idRealProfile;
private Gender gender;
private Age age;
private Income income;
// getters & setters
}
```

Gender, Age и Income - это энумы.
мне же надо определять, есть ли среди ключей тот, у которого совпадают с данным поля gender, age и income

Comment: Если вам нужен поиск не по ключу, может быть, вы пользуетесь неправильной структурой данных.

А так вообще пробегитесь по множеству ключей и сравнивайте.

Comment: мне нужен поиск по ключу: нужно искать знать, лежит ли среди ключей данный realProfile или нет. Сравнивать нужно не по всем полям.    
Думал применить метод .contain. Но он, почему то, все время выдает false

Comment: @Stas0n вы бы потрудились почитать документацию по Java Collections Framework, а также по методам equals() и hashCode(). А то задаете нелепые вопросы.

Есть отличный ресурс для изучения Java и стандартных библиотек (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

RealProfile - ключ

ArrayList<ModelledProfile> - значение

1. находишь по ключу объект
2. если есть - возвращаешь
3. проверяешь нужные поля

Comment: а можно просто как-то переписать метод equals?

Comment: Тут проблемка и еще в одном:   
заполнил мапу 2-мя ключами ( rp и rp2 ) и, оказалось, что    
out.println(example.containsValue(rp2));
возвращает false

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно нужно переопределять метод equals у RealProfile и в нем проверять нужные поля, если совпадают, то return true. А можно увидеть код вашей проблемы при заполнении мапы двумя ключами?